# Why does Android Studio 3.2.1 fail to interpret file content correctly--not even close--for half my project class files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've never seen anything like this, nor can I imagine how AS could interpret completely valid `*.java` files so weirdly. Here's a 3-part picture of the IDE. Note that the `*.java` files that are shown as such have been interpreted correctly. The one with red underline does not in fact look anything like that. The other neighboring files (ones withouot the `>`) are displayed as having similar crazy content.

So what's up?

I opened every `*.java` file in the project in Notepad++. All look fine. None resemble what's shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I exited AS and re-entered; problem persists.

The full text of the red message at the bottom is

```
    Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: 
SQhell. 
Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.
```

A message I found in a *different* project says 
`4:09 PM    Load Settings
                Cannot load settings from file 
'C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\SQhell\SQhell.iml': 
Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
                Please correct the file content`

Here's that file (`SQhell.iml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id="SQhell" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="java-gradle" name="Java-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="BUILD_FOLDER_PATH" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
        <option name="BUILDABLE" value="false" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_7" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

I deleted every AS-related folder (couldn't  uninstall; exported my settings first) and downloaded 3.2.1 a couple of weeks ago. No problems except with my own logic until this.

My app with build variants compiles fine as do smaller apps.

What should I do?

I don't even know how to Google this. What would I say? Has anyone seen such a problem before?

I'd also really like to know what *caused* this whacko scenario.

**EDIT**

I Googled `android studio not interpreting files correctly` and found nothing like this.

I suppose I could copy the project--or just the source files--to a different folder and see what happens.

I suppose I could uninstall and reinstall AS.

But how can this have happened???

***EDIT 2***

Here's `proguard.rules`. Line 1 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` flagged with the error below:

[image]

Here's "my" `.gitignore` in its entirety:

```
<applica
```

Here's other:

```
<application>
  <component name="RecentProjectsManager">
    <option name="recentPaths">
      <list>
        <option value="$U
```

Does this situation warrant a bug report?